# GnuBiff - Preferences

Tags: mail, mail-notification

I try to use GnuBiff as a mail notification with no avail.

My address mail is myname@yahoo.co.uk

So what settings shall I use at Preferances of GnuBiff ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The software seems abandoned, no updates since 6 years ago. It's possible it no longer works with the many changes Ubuntu experienced since then.

Comment: Thanks ChanganAuto . I have to look for another application.

Answer (score 0):

gnubiff works just fine.
After installing gnubiff, run the command gnubiff from the terminal.
You'll get the setup window (note, of some computers the window is bigger than the screen and, in order to CLOSE is and SAVE the parameters after configuring your account you might need to press ALT to move the window around).
Select mailbox 1 and click PROPERTIES.
Change mailbox 1 to your account name
change  TYPE to pop3 or imap
fill in the yahoo mail server datas and your account username password etc.
CLOSE the configuration window. That's all.
On login you can run gnubiff with the options 'gnubiff -n' to skip configuration and also 'gnubiff -n --systemtray' to have it run on the tray as a daemon.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My mail address is myname@yahoo.co.uk. At the properties window: The default name mailbox1 seems OK to me. Type Imap or POP you wrote that both are OK. Which Address shall I use ? What user name ? The "myname" is OK?. At password box shall I write the password I use to read my mails ? Thanks in advance. – 
Manolis
5 mins ago